# Rails 4 - Invite team mates to project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Im trying to add functionality to my Rails 4 app which allows a user (who creates a project) to invite others to join their project team.

I found this tutorial, which I've found helpful: https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails

To this point, I have the following set up:

User

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

Profile

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :teams, foreign_key: "team_mate_id"

  has_many :team_projects, through: :teams, source: :project
  has_many :invitations, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
```

Project

```
belongs_to :profile
    has_one :team
    has_many :team_mates, through: :team
    has_many :invites
```

Invite

```
 belongs_to :project
      belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'Profile'
      belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'Profile'
```

Team

```
belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :team_mate, class_name: "Profile"
```

In my form, I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@invite, :url => invites_path) do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @invite.project_id %>
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email %>
            <%= f.input :expiry, :as => :date_picker, :label => "When do you need a response to this invitation?"  %>

            <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
            <% end %>
```

Then in my show (rendered on the projects show) I have:

```
<%= render :partial => 'projects/invite_team_mate'  %>
```

In my invites controller, I have:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @invite = Invite.new
    end

    def create
      @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
      @invite.sender_id = current_user.profile.id
      if @invite.save

        #if the user already exists
        if @invite.recipient != nil 

           #send existing user email invitation to join project team
           InviteMailer.existing_user_invite(@invite).deliver 

           #Add the user to the user group - inivte rsvp pending
           @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)
        else
            #send new user email invitation to join as a user and this project team
           @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)

           # InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
        end
      else
         # oh no, creating an new invitation failed
      end
    end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invite
      @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invite_params
      params[:invite].permit(:email)
    end   
end
```

I can't figure out what else needs to happen to make this work.

When I save all this and try to invite an email address, I get this error:

```
undefined method `project' for nil:NilClass
```

That happens despite the form I use to send the invite being shown on the projects show page.

Comment: in the error trace, it will say what line it comes from. This will help you find which object is `nil` (some object you're calling `.project` on is `nil`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `project_id` and `recipient_id` to your invite_params, and add the recipient to your form (as a text_field, or hidden field, depending on your use case):

```
# controller
def invite_params
  params[:invite].permit(:email, :project_id, :recipient_id)
end   

# form
<%= simple_form_for(@invite, :url => invites_path) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.hidden_field :recipient_id, :value => get_recipient_id %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried that - thanks for the suggestion, but it gives this error: undefined method `project' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Sorry, updating the answer. You need to add recipient to invite_params as well.

Comment: Hi Anand, I tried that too, but  i still get the error: undefined method `project' for nil:NilClass
or did you mean that I should not use hidden field for project id?

Comment: In your view, @invite.project_id is not available, since your new action in the controller just has `@invite = Invite.new`. Where do you get the invite's project id from?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that Arand, can you give me a clue about where to look for that answer?

Comment: @Mel When you add a hidden_field for project_id, and trying to initialize it with a value, it means you already know the project related to this invitation. What method or logic will allow you to get the project_id? `@invite` does not likely have a project_id, since you just called `@invite = Invite.new` - there is just an empty `@invite` object. Does that help?

Comment: Hmmm. maybe I need to do @project.invite = Invite.new

Comment: Where will you get `@project` from? You could pass project_id into invites#new as a param, and then use: `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id]`, and plug in the project into the invite - `@invite = Invite.new(project_id: @project`

Comment: Hi Anand, I think your suggestion might have something in common with Mukesh's suggestion. Im not sure I understand how to solve this though. If I put project = Project.find(params[:project_id] in the new action of the invite controller, and then where do you suggest that I put: invite = Invite.new(project_id: @project?

Comment: '@' not included in the above comment because this comment form doesnt permit more than one of them

Answer (score 0):

**Error is due to @invite.project_id, because @invite has no data so it's throwing error**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @invite.project_id %>
```

replace this with or with some other desired logic

```
select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@projects, "id", "name")
```

In controlller

```
def new
  @invite = Invite.new
  @projects = current_user.team_projects // here you have to add your logic, for which project you want to invite or let me know 
end
```

Comment: Hi Mukesh, when I try that, I get this error: undefined method `project' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Hi Mukesh, I get the same error message when I try this

Comment: Hi Mukesh, what logic would I put in the project? would it be @invite.project?

Comment: @invite is new object, so it have nothing in current,

Comment: For which project you want to invite user, let me know please

Comment: Well, invite has a belong_to association with project, so I want the invite to belong to the project that has the partial form for @invite showing on it

Comment: Bro, you are not understanding, In controller @invites is new object so how you will map it with project...  which have nothing for example if user have a bike...but for bike a user should exist

Comment: Hi Mukesh, I'm sorry, I haven't understood the bike analogy. I am struggling to learn - I'm not sure what you mean. When a user creates a project, they can then invite others (registered or not) to join the project. If the user is not already a registered user, they first need to join the app.

Comment: Ok, For this make a drop down in your form for all projects of users and select every time  a project, for which you want to invite users before submit   form.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Mukesh - I'm pretty sure that's not what I'm trying to achieve though. I embed the invite form on a project page, so I should be able to know the associated project id. I don't know how to implement that in code, but that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding following code very strange

```
if @invite.recipient != nil 
    ...
   #Add the user to the user group - inivte rsvp pending
   @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)
else
    #send new user email invitation to join coalfacer and this project team
   @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)
   ...
end
```

How is that you call the same code @invite.recipient. even if @invite.recipient is Nil?!

By the way, ensure you understand why this code is written for in the controller, what it means

```
def invite_params
  params[:invite].permit(:email)
end
```

For your convenience, refrain from coping code you don't understand. Also, even if you do so, do that in small portions and try after each one, so you can localize the error if any. Working in small increments is essential. You can't do a horde of changes and then just ask "what's wrong about his plenty of code".

Finally, I suggest you write specific questions, using [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) principle. You have to extract specific portions of your code relevant to the issue, and be specific on the problem. If you put whole bunch of code, including irrelevant one, it's much much harder to help.

Comment: Hi Pavel. I wrote that line. I don't want to call the same code. The first line is if recipient is not nil (which means I have the user in the application already. The else has a commented note to say they need to be invited to join the app first before joining the project.

Comment: What's the purpose of calling @invite.recipient.project.push(...) in else statement after your checked that @invite.recipient is nil? You don't seem to create the recipient in this case, and, shall this line be called, will receive message "undefined method `project' for nil:NilClass" - because you call .project on @invite.recipient which you just ensured is nil.

Comment: Overall, after you just called @ invite = Invite.new(invite_params), so create a new invite object with just email set (based on invite_params method definition), how do you expect it may have @invite.recipient set? I.e. how it can not be nil?

Comment: Hi Pavel, the tutorial I linked in my post explains why these steps are taken. I'm trying to figure it out myself. I don't understand why changing the user controller as suggested in the tutorial is a good idea, given that not all new users will come from project invitations. I'm still trying to figure things out, but not sure what you suggest?

Comment: Mel, you had a question on why undefined method `project' for nil:NilClass
exception is raising. Based on your code, you make a call @ invite.recipient.project.push after checking that @ invite.recipient is nil. Making any call on nil object will cause the exception. So you have to substitute this call with something that works for invite that doesn't have recipient assigned. You have to create new recipient or something - that all depends on your code.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Pavel. I'll keep trying to figure out the tutorial I linked to.